# export mysql related tables to csv

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have 3 tables in a database that are related as follows:

```
fruit_names ----> data <---- features
```

with foreign key relations in data that relate to the names and features tables. So, there is a range of fruits and a range of features which are specified in separate tables, information on each feature for each fruit is given in the data table. In other words, each data row is associated with only one fruit name and one feature name; and other information on the fruits and the features is stored in the other two tables.

I want a csv that is formatted as a table, with the features as columns and the fruits on rows:

```
        roundness           enlongatedness          tastyness           difficulty_to_peel
apple   10 quite round      1 not enlongated        5 depends           2 very difficult
banana  1 not round at all  8 quite enlongated      10 always tasty     9 very easy
kiwi    8 little bit round  3 little bit enlongated 5 depends           7 easy
orange  10 quite round      1 not enlongated        6 most often tasty  7 easy
```

This command of course gives me the relevant information, but not in the right format:

SELECT fruit_names_name, data_x, features_feature_name
FROM data
JOIN features
ON data.features_foreign = features.features_id
JOIN languages
ON data.fruit_names_foreign = fruit_names.fruit_names_id;

as it presents the data in a table as follows:

```
fruit_names_name    data_x              features_feature_name
apple               10 quite round      roundness
apple               1 not enlongnated   enlongatedness
apple               3 depends           tastyness
apple               2 very difficult    difficulty_to_peel
banana              1 not round at all  roundness
banana              8 quite enlongated  enlongatedness
etc.
```

Is it possible to use phpmyadmin, a php script or mysql itself to generate a usable .csv file?

Comment: [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

Comment: Yes, I realise SELECT INTO OUTFILE is the way to go here. But how to combine the information from the three different tables into the required format? I have tried combining SELECT INTO OUTFILE with UNION, something like 
SELECT data_x FROM data 
UNION SELECT features_feature_name FROM features 
UNION SELECT fruit_names_name FROM fruit_names 
INTO OUTFILE /Users/....;
but this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could concactenate the fields like this:-

```
SELECT CONCAT(fruit_names_name, ', ', data_x, ', ', ... etc)
FROM data 
JOIN features 
ON data.features_foreign = features.features_id 
JOIN languages 
ON data.fruit_names_foreign = fruit_names.fruit_names_id;
```

and then copy the output into a text file

Comment: That still outputs the data in the list format, with every fruit name listed X times, then its feature, and then feature_names, listed for each row that is in data. This is not what I want, see question.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see that part.  You probably need a PIVOT or CROSSTAB - perhaps this link will assist: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table